# How to get the source app from a iOS share extension? The reminder app knows the text is shared from the notes app

Tags: ios, swift

When I share a note from iOS notes app into Reminders, the reminders is able to know that it is from the notes app, and display the notes app icon.

I have looked at NSExtensionContext etc and couldn't figure this out. Is this specific only to Apple Apps?

I am implementing a share extension that others can share to, however, I can't figure out how to get that I am getting a share from notes vs other apps.

Comment: What is your question? This should never have been upvoted.

Comment: I have updated the title and comments to make it clearer! Basically I want to see if within my share extension I can get the source app or not.